A function of specific form passing through two given points
Let
$$s(t; a_0)=a_{0}t^{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{t}{3T(a_0)}\right)$$
with $T(a_0)=\sqrt{\frac{6d}{a_{0}}}$ (where $d$ is some positive real constant).
Then, let
$$
s^*(t; a_0, t_w) = s\left(\frac{t-t_{w}}{1-\frac{t_{w}}{T}}; a_0\right).
$$
Essentially, this is the function $s$ starting from the point $t_w$ instead of zero. One can call it "lag" (see the picture).
$s$ (red) and $s^*$ (blue)
Say, I have two distinct points $(t_i, s_i)$ with $0 < t_i$, $\forall i \in \{1,2\}$. How do I find the parameters $a_0, t_w$ such that the lagged function $s^*(t; a_0, t_w)$ passes through these two points? Do such parameters exist? I am quite sure that there is no closed solution in this case, but one could solve this using a numerical method for a nonlinear system (e.g., multidimentional Newton's method). However, I am not sure this is the way to approach this.
